# How to deploy Spring web project on Heroku?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, heroku

I am trying to run Spring web project on Heroku. Not Spring Boot. I have deployed Spring Boot project before but now I need to deploy Spring web. How to do that? There's no solution online.

Comment: Can't you put in docker and deploy the docker image?

Comment: Where to put the docker?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker